# How to find administrator panel path in Joomla project

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

A few years ago I've created a site using Joomla. For security reasons I changed the path to the administrator panel using some module (e.g. Akeeba's Admin tools, but I'm not sure) and I don't remember this path nowadays. In which file this path is written?

Comment: Maybe you already did it... but I ask you anyway: do you inspected ftp? Do you inspected htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the administrator folder is defined in the file your-www-root/defines.php, with a line like

```
define('JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR', JPATH_ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'some_other_folder');
```

So try looking for a defines.php file in your www-root.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I solved this problem from different point of view. Instead of trying to find hashed path, I just disabled plugin that modified this path, so it became /administrator (standard path). For those who struggle with the same problem but don't want to disable plugin, I recommend to look for this path in db, instead of static files